# Bind Treeview to object with list of same object in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, nodes

I'm trying to make a report treeview thing. Where I could write some text to have as a parent node, and if need be I'd add add strings as sub nodes to display some more information.

I made a report object:

```
public class Report
{
    private List<Report> reportList = new List<Report>();

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Report> Reports
    {
        get
        {
            return reportList;
        }
        set
        {
            reportList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'd have a Report Collection that I would then feed into a treeview itemssource, but I have no idea how to create the bindings so that it will create the subnodes properly throughtout, I tried searching google, but I couldn't find the correct way.

Can anybody inhere help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Report}" ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Oh my...I thought I did that already, but I guess I must've messed up the bindings or something. Thanks a bunch. Could I perhaps ask a followup? Say I then had a person object who had: FirstName, LastName, Adress, Sex, Height. And in the parent node you'd only want to show the First and Last name, but in the subnodes they'd have all information (a master detail of sorts) I can't use hierachical data for that right?

Comment: @Xenoxsis: Instead of using the `DataType` property to select a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` based on the type of the element in the tree (which doesn't differentiate between same type of element at different levels) you can use the `ItemTemplate` property to specify another `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the next level.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ReportCollection}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```